# How to update a specific node based on another node in firebase realtime database android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have two parent node with some child. when i try to update one child from one node then another child node also should update. for example when i update time_slot (child node) 09:00AM to 10:00AM from one node then it should reflect in another node also.
Like in sql database foreign key concepts. if we update one primary key value then it will update in another table in which it is referred

[image]

Comment: Please post what have you tried so far.

Comment: if you have proper reference in your one document then it's easy to do it.

Comment: `15783...` is random generated id ?

Comment: Yes random generate @frankenstein

Answer (score 2):

**Firebase** is a noSQL database. So you cant expect SQL type behavior here. 
What you can do here is update both nodes directly from your mobile application. Second option is use **Cloud Functions** to trigger a database event.

To understand cloud functions please go through [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) .

Answer (score 0):

To update both, try the following:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Requests").child("1578311274538")
DatabaseReference timeRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("TimeSlot").child("01").child("01");
Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<String,Object>();
Map<String, Object> timeUpdates = new HashMap<String,Object>();
updates.put("time_slot", newdate);
timeUpdates.put("time_slot", newdate);

ref.updateChildren(updates);
timeRef.updateChildren(timeUpdates);
```

Basically, use `updateChildren()` to update the data in firebase. This is the only way and you need to have reference to the keys above the attribute that you need to update.

Comment: i don't think he will send the child reference hardcoded. It needs to be somewhere. above code will work for single transaction

Comment: Child reference will be auto generate id @Ashish

Comment: @KarthickJai when creating new document save the id of another document in it with new field then it's possible

Comment: @Peter Haddad will try your solution and let u know

Comment: @Ashish could you send me code  that if we create new node and saving the id of another node, how to update it same time

Comment: can you provide me both code you have tried then i'll provide proper code to you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205443/discussion-between-ashish-and-karthick-jai).

Comment: @KarthickJai when you auto-generated child reference store it Ina variable and pass it to the method

Answer (score 0):

You need to create model class for `Request` and also for `TimeSlot`.

```
    var firebaseApp =FirebaseApp.initializeApp(chatActivity)
    var firebaseDatabase=  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    var Db=firebaseDatabase?.getReference().child("Request").addValueEventListener(object :ValueEventListener{
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

        }

        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            //p0 have all the data off Request node 
            //now we will fetch its childern
            for (request in p0.children)
            {
              var requestModel=timeMsg.getValue(RequestModel::class.java) as RequestModel
             //requestModel have the all the data of 157...

             }
        }
    })
```

you can make the list for all request.