# How to update different node child at same time firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

i want to update timeslot based on condition for example when user booked a bike start time 09:00AM and end time 12:00PM then i want to update time slot from 09:00AM to 12:00AM availability false.
so is it possible to update different child at same time. or please give me a path how can i do this.

```
                DatabaseReference ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("TimeSlot").child(Common.BikeId);

            ref.orderByChild("TimeSlot").equalTo("10:00AM").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                   //update children


                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

in above code only one children i could update at a time 
how to solve this kind of solution.

Comment: How many accounts do you have https://stackoverflow.com/q/59611877/7015400

Comment: having account is problem here?

Comment: can we use for loop to update number of different children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all**, you can't compare `String` to match with `startAt` and `endAt` time. Instead use `long` value like **[0 - 24]** to hold the time in 24 hour format.

**And then**, execute below operation to update the child `isAvailable` to `false`

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
        .child("TimeSlot")
        .child(Common.BikeId);

ref.orderByChild("time_slot")
        .startAt(9.0)
        .endAt(12.0)
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for(DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    //Check whether child with key 'isAvailable' exist or not
                    if(childSnapshot.hasChild("isAvailable")) {

                        //Now update the status with false
                        ref.child(childSnapshot.getKey())
                                .child("isAvailable")
                                .setValue(false);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: thank you so much alot. your solution working like a charm.was spending a lot of hour for this issues. really your solution works perfect...once again thanks alot @Md Asaduzzaman